# Performing join on two dictionaries in Python on key

Tags: python, dictionary

The following is the list of job dictionaries:

```
[{'emp_id':1,'job_id':a},
{'emp_id':1,'job_id':b},
{'emp_id':1,'job_id':c},
{'emp_id':2,'job_id':d},
{'emp_id':3,'job_id':e},
{'emp_id':3,'job_id':f}]
```

The following is the list of employee dictionaries

```
[{'emp_id':1,'city':Tokyo},
{'emp_id':2,'city':Berlin},
{'emp_id':3,'city':Paris},
{'emp_id':4,'city':New York}]
```

My intention is to output results with each city and the number of employees in those cities who have done jobs.

I have done this using a cumbersome method involving loops

Is there a pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: `I have done this using a cumbersome method involving loops`. Code or it didn't happen :)

Comment: Also, show the expected output.

Comment: i also don't see any reference to employee numbers.

Comment: emp_id is the reference?

Comment: If you have a list, please post a list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of python's *pandas* library...

```
a = [{'emp_id':1,'job_id':'a'},
{'emp_id':1,'job_id':'b'},
{'emp_id':1,'job_id':'c'},
{'emp_id':2,'job_id':'d'},
{'emp_id':3,'job_id':'e'},
{'emp_id':3,'job_id':'f'}]

b = [{'emp_id':1,'city':'Tokyo'},
{'emp_id':2,'city':'Berlin'},
{'emp_id':3,'city':'Paris'},
{'emp_id':4,'city':'New York'}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

result = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='emp_id', how='left')
result.set_index('emp_id', inplace=True)

result = result.to_dict()
print(result)
```

This returns the following output:

```
{'job_id': {1: 'c', 2: 'd', 3: 'f'}, 'city': {1: 'Tokyo', 2: 'Berlin', 3: 'Paris'}}
```

Comment: Thanks but isnt there a non-panda solution?

Comment: If you just want to use python's standard library, you would have to use looping, which you've already done

Comment: @EchchamaNayak. If you are getting answers that you did not want, it's because your question is not clear. Please fix it.

Comment: @RileyHun Thanks. This looks cleaner and less cumbersome than my method.

Comment: @EnchchamaNayak My pleasure! Glad I was able to help